# How to create a new Pandas DataFrame from alternating boolean rows such that the new DataFrame is ready to plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I was hoping someone could help me figure out the best way to arrange my DataFrame to do a scatter plot. The scatter plot should have year on the x axis and percent Foreign Players on the y axis. The DataFrame has about 400 rows and for convenience I will show a head with fewer values.

I began with this DataFrame from a larger DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.head(5).loc[:, ['Year', 'Nationality', 'Foreign Player']]

    Year    Nationality Foreign Player
0   2016    United States   False
1   2016    United States   False
2   2016    United States   False
3   2016    United States   False
4   2016    United States   False
```

I did a groupby by year and foreign player making this a multi index DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Year','Foreign Player']).count()[['Player']].head(6)

                          Player
Year    Foreign Player  
2000    False              26
        True               2
2001    False              21
        True               5
2002    False              20
        True               5
```

I reset the index to make a single index DataFrame:

```
df3 = df2.reset_index(level = [0,1]).head(6)

    Year    Foreign Player  Player
0   2000    False             26
1   2000    True              2
2   2001    False             21
3   2001    True              5
4   2002    False             20
```

As You can see, the True and False are alternating with corresponding values in a different column.
I wanted to do something like:

```
df3['Percent Foreign'] = df3[['Foreign Player']= False] / (df3[['Foreign Player']= False ] + df3[['Foreign Player']= True)
```

Obviously that will not work. My objective is a new DataFrame:

```
    Year    Percent Foreign 
0   2000    15
1   2001    12          
2   2002    5           
3   2003    22          
4   2004    17
```

Such as then I can plot  x = Year and x = Percent Foreign using Matplotlib. By any means, if there is an easier way to plot this in an earlier step it would be even better.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For select `False` values is used innverting mask by `~`, convert values of `Year` to index and divide by aggregate `sum`:

```
print (df3)
  Year  Foreign Player  Player
0  2000           False      26
1  2000            True       2
2  2001           False      21
3  2001            True       5
4  2002           False      20
4  2002            True      10
```

---

```
df4 = (df3[~df3['Foreign Player']].set_index('Year')['Player'] / 
       df3.groupby('Year')['Player'].sum()).mul(100).reset_index(name='Percent Foreign')

print (df4)
   Year  Percent Foreign
0  2000        92.857143
1  2001        80.769231
2  2002        66.666667
```

Another idea is change `df2` by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df22 = df.groupby(['Year','Foreign Player'])['Player'].count().unstack()
print (df22)
Foreign Player  False  True 
Year                        
2000               26      2
2001               21      5
2002               20     10
```

And then divide `False` column by sum both columns:

```
df4 = (df22[False] / df22.sum(axis=1)).mul(100).reset_index(name='Percent Foreign')

print (df4)
   Year  Percent Foreign
0  2000        92.857143
1  2001        80.769231
2  2002        66.666667
```

For percentage of `True`s:

```
df5 = (df22[True] / df22.sum(axis=1)).reset_index(name='Percent Foreign')
```

Comment: @Alejandro - tested and corrected, sorry.

Comment: Awesome, I checked it again and it works. Only Issue is that it's giving me the %True not the %False. So I just removed the ~ before df3. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To get ratio of players, an idea to make two new columns which count total players and total foreign players, and then a third column which divides the aggregated two columns.

Example - simplified dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'Year': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011], 
  'Foreign Player': [True, True, False, True, False, False, True, True]}
)


Year    Foreign Player
0   2010    True
1   2010    True
2   2010    False
3   2010    True
4   2011    False
5   2011    False
6   2011    True
7   2011    True
```

Count rows and foreigners

```
df_agg = df.groupby('Year')['Foreign Player'].agg(['count', 'sum'])
```

Find ratio:

```
df_agg['ratio'] = df_agg['sum']/df_agg['count']


df_agg

count   sum ratio
Year            
2010    4   3   0.75
2011    4   2   0.50
```